# Unable to install firebase in react using npm install firebase : Displaying multiple errors

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install firebase but unable to do so..
Tried multiple solutions:
npm cache clean --force
npm install --save react-firebase

Please Help!

PS C:\Users\SharmaShashtra\amzclone> npm install firebase
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-currency-format@1.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.9.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.9.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.8.7
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!         peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.8.4
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.8.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.8.4
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.8.4" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/styled@11.9.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.8.7
format@1.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-currency-format
npm ERR!     react-currency-format@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\SharmaShashtra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SharmaShashtra\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-09-06T13_43_06_559Z-debug-0.log

---UPDATE---

Had to force install everything, and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are in the right directory.

Comment: C:\Users\SharmaShashtra\amzclone>
This is where I'm trying to install...
After your comment used cd.. and then installed just fine...But not working on my project dir